# Lowpass/Bandpass filter design in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, communication, lowpass-filter

For an analog communication system design in MATLAB firstly I need to do these two design:

1. Design a low-pass filter `[slow]=lowpassfilter(s,fcut,fs)` which filters input signal `s` with cutoff frequency `fcut` and sampling frequency `fs` in Hertz.
2. Design a band-pass filter `[sband]=bandpassfilter(s,fcutlow,fcuthigh,fs)` which filters input signal `s` with cutoff frequencies `fcutlow` and `fcuthigh` and sampling frequency `fs` in Hertz.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

I found this question which has so many views and still no good answer.

The following code will do what you need. Since no filter-type is specified, I used a butterworth-filter to demonstrate it. `s` is the input signal and `x` is the filtered signal. `fs` is the sampling rate in Hz.

```
% Design and apply the lowpass filter
order = 4;
fcut  = 8000;
[b,a] = butter(order,fcut/(fs/2),'low');
x     = filter(b,a,s);


% Design and apply the bandpass filter
order    = 10;
fcutlow  = 1000;
fcuthigh = 2000;
[b,a]    = butter(order,[fcutlow,fcuthigh]/(fs/2), 'bandpass');
x        = filter(b,a,s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has `fdatool` for filter design purposes. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/fdatool.html) is the documentation. You can do all these tasks using `fdatool` and the signal processing toolbox.

Comment: Yes I know but the point is I need to take inputs from the outputs of other functions so I have no specific values for fcut or fs. So When I write fs in it, it gives an error :S

Comment: I guess you should change the wording of your question. If you somehow know fs (apriori), you can just check the fft of the signal in order to determine the frequency bands you wanna filter.